# Error message in android eclipse

Tags: drawable

I'm getting this error message, why is that?

> [2014-07-08 22:30:16 - journey] res\drawable\abc_spinner_ab_holo_light (1).xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>
> [2014-07-08 22:30:16 - journey] res\drawable\abc_spinner_ab_holo_light (1).xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>
> [2014-07-08 22:30:16 - journey] res\drawable\abc_spinner_ab_holo_light (1).xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>
> [2014-07-08 22:30:16 - journey] res\drawable-xhdpi\abc_tab_selected_focused_holo.9.png:0: error: Resource entry abc_tab_selected_focused_holo is already defined.
>
> [2014-07-08 22:30:16 - journey] res\drawable-xhdpi\abc_tab_selected_focused_holo.9 (1).png:0: Originally defined here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a problem caused by copy and paste.

Remove the " (1)" from the files names.

For example "abc_spinner_ab_holo_light (1).xml"  should be renamed to "abc_spinner_ab_holo_light.xml".

For this one "abc_tab_selected_focused_holo.9.png" make it "abc_tab_selected_focused_holo.png"

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've fixed it.
In my android-support-v7-appcompat project, I don't know why, but it duplicated those files.
I've just delete them.